# htaccess allow access (Disable authorization) to file if query string exists WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to allow user to wordpress wp-admin index page if query string contains parameter. I am setting env variable to allow them access. This is how my htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^author=1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_AUTH:1]

AuthName "Staff Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /usr/bin/.htpasswd

<Files "index.php">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require user newagenumber

Allow from env=NO_AUTH

</Files>

Options -Indexes
```

As of yet, authorization dialog box appears for everyone. Please help :|

Comment: Where you have set the `NO_AUTH` variable?

Comment: RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_AUTH:1]

Comment: And what is valid url user should see the Auth box?

Comment: if the url is XXX.com?author=1 then they shouldn't see the authBox otherwise they should.

Answer (score 3):

This is not working because Apache executed `mod_auth` module before `mod_rewrite` hence `NO_AUTH` is not set when basic authentication directives run.

Unfortunately this behavior is not that simple to change.

Here is a workaround solution that combines `mod_rewrite`, `mod_setenvif` and `mod_auth`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-admin/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(author=1)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ index.php/%1 [NC]

# set SECURED var to 1 if URI is /index.php/200
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/index\.php/(author=1)" NO_AUTH

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require user newagenumber

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Same behavior as before

Comment: See updated code. btw this is fully tested and working code in my .htaccess. What URL do you see in your browser?

Comment: I believe you are trying to change the url to index.php/author but looks like its not even changing the url.

Comment: That is internal rewrite only. You need to enter `http://example.com/index.php?author=1` in your browser to make it work

Comment: Nope, this is the actual site.
    newagenumber.com/wp-admin/index.php?author=1

Comment: You never told before about `wordpress` or `/wp-admin/` in URI? It is very difficult to get it working with WP. See updated code and try placing above in `/wp-admin/.htaccess`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have updated with your code but still no luck

Comment: Nice explanation to complex problem, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks. @AsifAlamgir: Try entering URL as `http://example.com/wp-admin/index.php/author=1` and see if this gets auth dialog or not.

Comment: nope. Is it possible to do the same functionality with php instead of htaccess?

Comment: Yes sure PHP can do it but you need to read WP guide on how to do it.

Comment: For anyone who might be trying this similar functionality, I have added an if statement in wp-admin/index.php to check for get status and display auth box accordingly before loading the bootstrap.